# SQL Server 2014: Using gMSA for xp_cmdshell Proxy Account?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, xp-cmdshell

We are running SQL Server 2014. We want to use a gMSA as the proxy account for xp_cmdshell.

I tried running the following:

```
EXEC sys.sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'gmsaNameGoesHere$', ''
```

However, it expects a password.

I tried running the following:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL ##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account## WITH IDENTITY = 'gmsaNameGoesHere$'
```

It runs! However, when the user tries to run xp_cmdshell via the proxy account, they're told:

> Msg 15153, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 3 The
>   xp_cmdshell proxy account information cannot be retrieved or is
>   invalid. Verify that the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential
>   exists and contains valid information.

Is it possible to use a gMSA as the proxy account for xp_cmdshell in SQL Server 2014? If so, how do I set it up as the proxy account?

Thanks!

Comment: good chance this will be better answered on the dba.stackexchange.com sister site.

Comment: Thanks; I'll post it there. Sorry for posting in the wrong place!

Comment: No worries, there is a lot of overlap between the two...just want to make sure it's spotted by the right audience for you to get an answer.  Voted to close and move